# Making different sized prints

Tags: adobe-illustrator, page-layout

I'm redoing a logo for a local community/cultural group, as a Illustrator file so it can be scaled.  I've never used Illustrator before, but am handy with Photoshop.

I set up the project to fill a standard “letter” page.  That's the exemplar, but I will want to incorporate it into other projects or use in different ways.

In particular, I need a sign 24″×21½″.  I don't see any option to change the scale of an artboard, and poking around other posts I take it there is no such feature.  How *should* I modify the exemplar into what I want after opening the file?

I don't know how they are printing the file: I presume taking the file to a Kinkos or sign maker shop of some kind, so it needs to be turnkey.

I don't just want to put the logo on another page and scale it as a single lump; I need to adjust the proportions and shift elements to fit the aspect ratio and so on.  In **this case**, the resized page will become the new exemplar, as I'll incorporate feedback about nuances that still need work.

Comment: Downvote without explaination, somebody? It is not over specific but useful for everyone: it is an obvious thing to need, normal enough in *other* vector dtawing and CAD, and it's gone a month without any criticism.  So pray tell wht's *your* problem with it?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the size of the artboard in Illustrator by selecting the Artboard Tool (Shift + O) and adjusting the W and H options in the context toolbar most likely at the top of your window. If the units are in pts, you might need to change the ruler to inches first.

Tips in for Illustrator for a Photoshop person:

- Make sure you convert any fonts to outlines to prevent font substitution problems.
- If any shapes have a Stroke, make sure to have Scale Strokes and Effects checked so when you scale the art, your stroke width will scale as well.
- Center your art easily on the new artboard by selecting everything, Command+G to Group it together, then with the Selection Tool you'll get a context toolbar that allows you to Horizontal Align Center and Vertical Align Center on the artboard.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing what I consider the "wrong" way and with more work, since nobody Identified any way to just change the scale so the resulting page in PDF shows the enlarged size.

- Resize the artboard,
- select all, and scale the selection.
- *some things did not scale right* (this is not the stoke scale— that was checked) so then I had to fix things.

---

There were only a few elements, but in a complex case with more scrambling I think I would have given up and told them they must print-to-fit themselves.  That means out-of-band instructions that the clerk will, have to see, understand, and follow.

It occurs to me now that I might be able to resize the page (with its contents like "print to fit", *not* like resizing the artboard) in Acrobat.

There must be a way of *really* resizing a complex group without things losing their positions or getting funny results in some of the grouped contents; it might be desirable to place different existing logos and stock elements on a new page where they need to be resized by different amounts.

Answer (score -1):

If they want you design a sign, place the logo into a new file set up to the size you want. Otherwise, just send them the logo and they can use it as they see fit. Usually, you create the vector logo at the most common 'actual size' but as it's vector, it doesn't really matter. Anyone can scale it up or down with any compatible software.

Comment: Read the last paragraph of the question.

Comment: @jdlugosz I guess I don't understand your problem as to why things aren't scaling proportionately for you.